# Can I avoid being given a Strunk and White badge please?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm horrified to see that I am well on the way to being given a Strunk and White badge. Can I avoid wearing it please? Can I elect to have a Fowler's Modern English Usage badge instead? I hate Strunk and White. If I am writing the way Strunk and White would have me write, I am making a bad mistake. Please can I turn this award down?

Comment: Not sure if you're actually serious here? At best I can potentially see this as a feature-request to rename a badge, but, seriously?

Comment: Yes, seriously, I don't want people looking at my profile to think that I am a follower of Strunk and White.

Comment: I doubt many reasonable people will read the badge name and assume that's the case without looking to see what the badge is for. If you're _really_ that worried about it, you can always put a disclaimer in your "about me"

Comment: I still prefer "galley slave" for editing badge...

Comment: Is Strunk & White the W3Schools of writing or something?

Comment: @BilltheLizard - If it is, I'd actually vote up a feature request to rename it. OP would have to be more specific than "I don't like Strunk & White" though.

Comment: It's better than a Funk and Wagnells badge.

Comment: Wow, 14 downvotes. How many do I need for a badge?

Comment: @MartinJames - Is it though?

Answer (score 18):

*Snarky answer*: Sure. Just don't [edit 80 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white).

*Actual answer*: I'm afraid not.

The badge names are meant to be fun and evocative. At least in the United States, "Strunk & White" is generally associated with editing because many of us were forced to read it in high school. Other than "omit needless words" I doubt many of us actually remember anything about the text itself.

Changing the name might be pleasing to people, such as yourself, who do not care for the grammatical philosophy of Strunk & White. But what would we call the badge? Fowler's Modern English Usage fails to capture the (no doubt undeserved) popular recognition of the current name. We could, perhaps, find another synonym for editor, but would it strike the imagination in the same way as the existing name?

Finally, changing badge names to assuage differing belief systems is a slippery slope I don't think we can navigate. I personally know people who would be appalled to wear the [guru badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru). Those people probably could stand to lighten up a bit.

Comment: Actually, I suspect "Strunk and White" means absolutely nothing to most readers outside the US. I only came across it because I wrote a book for a US-based publisher. And I hated it because it seemed to be full of the rules that we were taught by small-minded school-teachers and spent the rest of our lives moving on from.

Comment: @MichaelKay: If the badge names are to be evocative at all, they're going to have to be inspired by some particular culture. Since most of SE is American, that's the culture you get. So the only real alternative is to remove all the clever badge names and make them plain and boring (and probably a lot longer).

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes, I have no idea who they are (other than just now because I Googled them.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Most of the badges (including this one) were named very early on when all the employees were from the US. Now we are a bit more international so new badge names are less likely to be country-specific references. [Or maybe not.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246252/1438)

Comment: "The badge names were meant to be fun and evocative". Unfortunately humour doesn't travel well. To anyone outside the US, if they have heard of Strunk and White at all, the term is synoymous with "American English". You are effectively labelling people as American, and no-one wants to be labelled as part of a culture they do not belong to. Assertions like "most of SE is American" belong with US-centric myths like "Edison invented the light-bulb" - it's time you travelled more widely.

Comment: Yes, I was going to mention the "guru" badge as well. It's highly insensitive to make people wear such badges if they don't like them. The simple answer is to allow anyone to "disclaim" a badge if they don't want it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Just to reinforce that point, https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#trafficCard (which is itself very US-biased) shows that 25% of SO traffic is from the US. Particularly remarkable is the high percentage of Asian ethnicity. It also shows that I'm in a clear minority being over 60 - perhaps older people are more inclined to dislike the whole badge/reputation/reward culture.

Comment: Sadly, StackOverflow has now forced me to wear the Strunk and White badge despite my protestations. I wear it with shame.